# JavaScript: Writing Arrays localStorage Results in Duplicate Items - Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

trying to write a javascript quiz for my coding bootcamp.  having some issues with retrieving and saving previous high scores from local storage.  can someone please explain to me why the below code writes the newScore TWICE to the highScores arrayItems array into local storage?  obviously i would not like duplicates.  everything else works great except for this!  please help me.  thank you so much!

```
// load any existing high scores from local storage as array

let scoresArray = localStorage.getItem('highScores') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('highScores')) : [];

// save the score and intials to local storage in array

let newScore = [document.querySelector("#initialsInput").value, '' + countdownTimer + ''];
scoresArray.push(newScore);

localStorage.clear("highScores");

localStorage.setItem('highScores', JSON.stringify(scoresArray));

// run the high scores function which will show all high scores, storted and give the user a chance to play again

showHighScores();
```

thanks for your quick replies.  im sorry i was able to supply you with all of the info you needed, but i thought i gave you enough to work with.

i was just writing to let you know i did figure out a work around. while i'm still getting the duplicate entries into the array, before writing it to localstorage i am using a very simple jquery method to remove any duplicates from my array.   here's what i ended up doing:

```
 var uniqueNames = [];
        $.each(scoresArray, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        })
```

Comment: Not enough shown to give any indication of why they get repeated. We don't know when or how you run what is shown or what `showHighScores()` does. Take a few minutes to read through creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> The clear() method of the Storage interface clears all keys stored in
> a given Storage object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear

I guess you don't need to clear the localStorage.

Comment: Shouldn't even need `clear()` since `setItem()` will overwrite any existing value for same key anyway

Comment: yeah, also for the solution be sure you are not calling this event twice

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the scenario of how triggering this implementation of adding array to the local storage, as I think you might add it twice instead (I mean if the code you showed us is inside a function or how it's executed exactly)
but from the code above, everything seems to be working fine, I'd like to have more code from your side please to better understand what's going on. also you can remove `localStorage.clear` as `localStorage.setItem` will override any existing key with new value

Answer (score 0):

lame work around using jquery to remove duplicates from the array:

```
var uniqueNames = [];
        $.each(scoresArray, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        })
```